# How to schedule background tasks in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alarms

I'm working in an Android application to collect data through forms... So, I have two important dates to synchronize the data collected to my server: a) Period of Synchronization, which takes values like WEEKLY, MONTHLY, etc... and b) Date of Campaign Finalization, which takes also the values WEEKLY, MONTHLY, etc; but it also can take values specified by the user... however, b) must be higher or equal to a)...A campaign can have several periods of synchronization...

So, to a), if its value is WEEKLY, I have to take the system date and then calculate the date 7 days forward... For b) I always have the date specified... When a) is reached, then the app must synchronize the data collected and forbid the edition of the forms or delete the data collected (if specified.).. When b) is reached, then the app must synchronize the data collected and delete them on purpose... If a) is higher than b) (as a result of date calculation), a) has to take the same value than b) and the event related to b) is triggered...

What I want to do now is to schedule two task: one for a) and one for b). This procedures have to be activated once the device's operator synchronizes for the first time data from the server. And they must executed in background, because they do a HTTP connection.

Can anyone guide me through this? Which is the best way to do this? I have read a lot about AlarmManager but all the examples I read are too simple and for notifications... Please help! Is kind of urgent!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html). Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xHXn3Kg2IQE), there you can find some explanations why it's the best choice.